# React : Pass param to render component with amplify

Tags: reactjs, react-native

Im fairly new to React and stuck with issue. I have a index.tsx which renders App component as below.

index.tsx

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import './index.css';
import App from './App';
import * as serviceWorker from './serviceWorker';
import {initialize} from './util/initialize';

initialize().then(settings => {
    ReactDOM.render(<App settings={settings}/>, document.getElementById('root'));
});    

serviceWorker.unregister();
```

App.tsx

```
import React from "react";
import Search from "./search/Search";
import { withAuthenticator, AmplifySignOut } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';

import "./App.css";

function App(settings : any) {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <AmplifySignOut />
        <Search indexId={settings.ID!} region={settings.REGION!}/>
      </div>
    );
}

export default withAuthenticator(App);
```

I am trying to pass the settings object from index.tsx to App component but I keep getting errors

```
Type '{ settings: any; }' is not assignable to type 'IntrinsicAttributes & { children?: ReactNode; }'.
```

Answer (score 0):

`settings` is being used as a prop in your index.tsx file. `App` will accept one argument (usually called `props`) that is an object containing all of your props. Try this and see if it helps you:

`function App({settings}: {settings: any}) {`

Comment: No it dint..still same error...
in export default withAuthenticator(App);

Comment: Is that the complete TS error? If not, can you post the complete error.